# removing null/empty values in lists of a json object in python recursively

Tags: python, json, string, list, null

I have a json object (json string) which has values like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "object_k_id": "",
      "object_type": "report",
      "object_meta": {
         "source_id": 0,
         "report": "Customers"
      },
      "description": "Daily metrics for all customers",
      "business_name": "",
      "business_logic": "",
      "owners": [
         "nn@abc.com",
          null
      ],
      "stewards": [
         "nn@abc.com",
         ''
      ],
      "verified_use_cases": [
         null,
         null,
         "c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20",
         null
      ],
      "classifications": [
         null
      ],
      "domains": []
   }
]
```

Bu the final format I want is something that has removed the nulls and the empty list items: something like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "object_k_id": "",
      "object_type": "report",
      "object_meta": {
         "source_id": 0,
         "report": "Customers"
      },
      "description": "Daily metrics for all customers",
      "business_name": "",
      "business_logic": "",
      "owners": [
         "nn@abc.com"
      ],
      "stewards": [
         "nn@abc.com"
      ],
      "verified_use_cases": [
         "c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20"
      ],
      "classifications": [],
      "domains": []
   }
]
```

I want the output to exclude nulls, empty strings and make it look more clean.
I need to do this recursively for all the lists in all the jsons I have.

Even more than recursive, it would be helpful if I can do it at one stretch rather than looping through each element.

I need to clean only the lists though.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your json string here is not valid

Comment: Note: `''` should be replaced with `""`, then it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json


def recursive_dict_clean(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v[:] = [i for i in v if i]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            recursive_dict_lookup(v)


data = json.loads("""[{
    "id": 1,
    "object_k_id": "",
    "object_type": "report",
    "object_meta": {
        "source_id": 0,
        "report": "Customers"
    },
    "description": "Daily metrics for all customers",
    "business_name": "",
    "business_logic": "",
    "owners": [
        "nn@abc.com",
        null
    ],
    "stewards": [
        "nn@abc.com"
    ],
    "verified_use_cases": [
        null,
        null,
        "c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20",
        null
    ],
    "classifications": [
        null
    ],
    "domains": []
}]""")


for d in data:
    recursive_dict_clean(d)

print(data):
[{'id': 1,
  'object_k_id': '',
  'object_type': 'report',
  'object_meta': {'source_id': 0, 'report': 'Customers'},
  'description': 'Daily metrics for all customers',
  'business_name': '',
  'business_logic': '',
  'owners': ['nn@abc.com'],
  'stewards': ['nn@abc.com'],
  'verified_use_cases': ['c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20'],
  'classifications': [],
  'domains': []}]
```

P.S.: Your json string is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `json` to `dict` then use the `function` below and convert it to `json` again:

```
def clean_dict(input_dict):
    output = {}
    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            output[key] = clean_dict(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            output[key] = []
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    output[key].append(clean_dict(item))
                elif value not in [None, '']:
                    output[key].append(item)
        else:
            output[key] = value
    return output
```

Thanks to N.O

Comment: Hey , tried this but still getting None values in the output like this:

'verified_use_cases': [None, None, 'c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20', None], 'classifications': [None], 'domains': None}

Comment: @monster can you send me your input, so I can test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt `object_pairs_hook` to parse the data as you decode it from your string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load

This function runs ever time the decoder might call `dict()` and removes all `None` objects from lists as it goes using a simple list comprehension, otherwise leaving the data alone and letting the decoder do it's thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
data_string = """[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "object_k_id": "",
      "object_type": "report",
      "object_meta": {
         "source_id": 0,
         "report": "Customers"
      },
      "description": "Daily metrics for all customers",
      "business_name": "",
      "business_logic": "",
      "owners": [
         "nn@abc.com",
          null
      ],
      "stewards": [
         "nn@abc.com",
         ""
      ],
      "verified_use_cases": [
         null,
         null,
         "c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20",
         null
      ],
      "classifications": [
         null
      ],
      "domains": []
   }
]"""

def json_hook(obj):
    return_obj = {}
    for k, v in obj:
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = [x for x in v if x is not None]

        return_obj[k] = v

    return return_obj

data = json.loads(data_string, object_pairs_hook=json_hook)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "object_k_id": "",
        "object_type": "report",
        "object_meta": {
            "source_id": 0,
            "report": "Customers"
        },
        "description": "Daily metrics for all customers",
        "business_name": "",
        "business_logic": "",
        "owners": [
            "nn@abc.com"
        ],
        "stewards": [
            "nn@abc.com",
            ""
        ],
        "verified_use_cases": [
            "c4a48296-fd92-3606-bf84-99aacdf22a20"
        ],
        "classifications": [],
        "domains": []
    }
]
```

in your example you remove the `""` value from `stewards`, if you want that behaviour, you can replace `is not None` with `not in (None, "")`.. but it seemed like that might've been a mistake since you left empty strings in other places.